# react native TextInput autoFocus in function component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using tab bar navigation and there is a tab called "search". When I go to search screen i need to auto focus to TextInput. It works fine for the first time. If i go to another tab and go back search screen again it doesn't work. I don't use componentDidMount so is there any other way to do that?

this is the useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    return null;
  }, []);
```

And Here is the textInput from nativeBase

```
<Input
          placeholder={'Ürün ara'}
          value={barcodes}
          onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
          onSubmitEditing={event => {
            if (event.nativeEvent.text.length === 13) {
              getir(event.nativeEvent.text);
            }
          }}
          keyboardType="number-pad"
          autoFocus
          blurOnSubmit={false}
          contextMenuHidden={true}
          maxLength={13}
          style={{
            paddingRight: dimensions.width * 0.125,
            paddingLeft: dimensions.width * 0.03,
          }}
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ref to focus your TextInput

```
const inputRef = useRef(null);
const onFocusHandler = () => {
 inputRef.current && inputRef.current.focus();
}
useEffect(() => {
    onFocusHandler();
}, []);

return (
 <>
  <Input 
          ref={inputRef} 
          placeholder={'Ürün ara'}
          value={barcodes}
          onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
          onSubmitEditing={event => {
            if (event.nativeEvent.text.length === 13) {
              getir(event.nativeEvent.text);
            }
          }}
          keyboardType="number-pad"
          autoFocus={true}
          onFocus={onFocusHandler}
          blurOnSubmit={false}
          contextMenuHidden={true}
          maxLength={13}
          style={{
            paddingRight: dimensions.width * 0.125,
            paddingLeft: dimensions.width * 0.03,
          }}
  />
 </>
)
```

Comment: that didnt work 

inputRef.current.focus() is undefined